# source code to transmit data using CAN protocol using C++

Tags: c++, can-bus

I'm using a QT creator application. In my application I need to transmit and receive data's using CAN protocol using C++ source code.

I searched a lot on Google also, but I was not able to find the source code for this.

Comment: How are you connected to your CAN Bus?

Comment: This site is about asking specific programming problems or patterns, also showing you've tried something and are stuck in the process. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to know what's on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independent of language, first understand the CAN protocol (ie, formation of data packets), and the different layers used, and what is the underlying physical transport. Since this involves more than one system you should start with a reference implementation, like the Discovery board, or other boards referenced in http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:822343/FULLTEXT01.pdf, or http://www.keil.com/forum/22051/can-bus-on-lpc2129/